# `go mod tidy` complains that the bazel-generated protobuf package is missing

Tags: go, bazel, gazelle

I have a `.proto` protobuf definition file in a dir and I'm building a go library from it with Bazel like so (`BUILD.bazel` file below generated using `gazelle`):

```
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_library")
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//proto:def.bzl", "go_proto_library")

proto_library(
    name = "events_proto",
    srcs = ["events.proto"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = ["@com_google_protobuf//:timestamp_proto"],
)

go_proto_library(
    name = "proto_go_proto",
    importpath = "github.com/acme/icoyote/proto",
    proto = ":events_proto",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

go_library(
    name = "proto",
    embed = [":proto_go_proto"],
    importpath = "github.com/acme/icoyote/proto",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Some other code depends on `//icoyote/proto:proto`, and when I run `go mod tidy` in my module, it complains that it can't find the package `github.com/acme/icoyote/proto`:

```
go: finding module for package github.com/acme/icoyote/proto
github.com/acme/icoyote/cmd/icoyote imports
        github.com/acme/icoyote/proto: no matching versions for query "latest"
```

Any IDE that doesn't have Bazel integration (e.g. VSCode, GoLand/IntelliJ without the Bazel plugin) complains as well

What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening of course because because Bazel **does** generate `.go` files using `protoc` under the covers for the `go_proto_library` rule in the `BUILD` file, but only writes them out to a temp dir under `bazel-bin` to be used by the `go_library` rule, and `go mod tidy` doesn't seem look into `bazel-bin` (probably because it's a symlink but also if it did, the path of those files relative to the location of `go.mod` is all wrong)

One option is to manually generate the go files by calling `protoc` on your own, and remove the `proto_library` and `go_proto_library` rules in the `BUILD` file, then change the `go_library` rule to build your generated files. This is suboptimal because you have to manually rerun `protoc` every time you make changes to the `.proto` file (and if you put it into a `//go:generate` directive, you have to rerun `go generate`).

Instead, we can do the following:

1. Add a file `empty.go` to the dir that contains the `.proto` file. It should look like this:

```
package proto
```

2. Then tell `gazelle` to ignore `empty.go` (so it doesn't try to add a `go_library` rule to the `BUILD` file when you run `gazelle --fix`). We do that by adding the following to the `BUILD` file:

```
# gazelle:exclude empty.go
```

That's enough to make `go mod tidy` shut up.

This will also make the IDE stop complaining about the import, although you'll still get errors when referring to anything that's supposed to be in that package. If you don't want to abandon your IDE for an excellent GoLand or IntelliJ IDEA with a Bazel plugin, you might have to resort to the manual `protoc` method. Perhaps there's a way to create a symlink to wherever Bazel writes out the generated `.go` files under `bazel-bin` and force `go mod tidy` to follow it, but I haven't tried that. If you do and it works, do share!